# How to reset multiple spinner values to default

Tags: android, spinner, default-value

I'm building the a app which has more than 20 spinners. I'm trying to reset all spinners with one click. is that possible? could you please guide me on how to achieve this. below is my codes.

If possible i want the reset to be selected from menu ( 3 dots on top right) can someone please assist me. thank you in advance :)

```
package com.example.hfacs_test09;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Unsafe extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener  {

private Spinner uhs1a,uhs1b,uhs1c;
private TextView unsaferesult;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unsafe, container, false);    

    unsaferesult = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.unsaferesult);

    uhs1a = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.uhs1a);
    uhs1b = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.uhs1b);
    uhs1c = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.uhs1c);

    uhs1a.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    uhs1b.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    uhs1c.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id){

   //uhs1a.setSelection(position);


   int r1 = Integer.valueOf((String) uhs1a.getSelectedItem());

   int r2 = Integer.valueOf((String) uhs1b.getSelectedItem());

   int r3 = Integer.valueOf((String) uhs1c.getSelectedItem());

   int total = r1 + r2 + r3;

   //int myresult = (Integer) uhs1a.getSelectedItem() ;

   unsaferesult.setText("Total Score is " + total);

 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**To reset a spinner to default value:**

```
uhs1a = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.uhs1a); // Ignore this if you already did that in onCreateView 
uhs1a.setSelection(0); // Assuming the default position is 0.
```

To do that for all the spinners, either you do that manually for every spinner, or you add all spinners to an ArrayList and then

```
for(int i=0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++)
    myArrayList.get(i).setSelection(0);
```

**To do that from the Menu (3 dots) button:**

```
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml_file, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.reset_button:

        // Reset spinners here.

        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the accurate information! it works after following your code. I really appreciate your time. Thank you again.

Comment: @Alexis you're absolutely welcome! Please accept this answer as the correct answer. If you need any more help, please ask me. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is same as single spinner.

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

just do this for all the spinners in your onclick of the button method.

Answer (score 0):

`your_spinner.setSelection(0);`
 
// it will  set your spinner to position 1.
 
// if you pass 1 it will set to position 2.....